# How can I install a go package with MinGW which depends on libiconv

Tags: windows, gcc, go, mingw, libiconv

I am currently trying to set up a Go project, and considering I am running Windows, while the other 2 developers are working on a Mac, I have some trouble with installing a few packages.

After trying to install the packages with cmd, I was only able to install 2 out of 4. The other two needed gcc.

Therefore, I installed MinGW. I was able to install a third package that way, but now I am stuck on https://github.com/mikkyang/id3-go.

It seems to depend on another underlying project, https://github.com/djimenez/iconv-go. The moment I try to `go install` id3-go, I am always left with this error:

```
src\github.com\djimenez\iconv-go\converter.go:8:19: fatal error: iconv.h: No such file or directory
```

Somehow, I need to use libiconv with MinGW, but I have no idea how to connect both parts. I'm not really an expert in that field, so any help would be appreciated a lot. I already downloaded libiconv for Windows.

Related issue for additional information I found on the github project:
https://github.com/mikkyang/id3-go/issues/21

EDIT: I made some progress on the whole problem. I now got all the files I need, but now I am stuck with this warning:

```
# github.com/djimenez/iconv-go
E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -liconv
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to add the libiconv2.a from my libiconv installation to the mingw32 lib folder, but then this is what I end up with:

```
# github.com/djimenez/iconv-go
E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
E:/Tools/TDM-GCC/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -liconv
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea how to proceed from here.

Comment: What packages are these that need `gcc`?

Comment: It's id3-go: https://github.com/mikkyang/id3-go

Comment: I don't see any use of compilation in that package.

Comment: I recommend vagrant for developing in windows.

Comment: @eduncan911 Well, I don't know the interna, but thats what I end up with when trying to run my project in IntelliJ. I performed "go get" for the package beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've met the same problem when I want to `go install github.com/google/gopacket` which need `CGO`. It's because your `libiconv2.a` is generated by other compiler, so it's incompatible with mingw32 compiler as the error message says. We need generate the static lib with the mingw32 toolset:

1. find libiconv-2.dll(the coresonding dynamic library) in your PC
2. run `gendef`(located in C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin in my 64-bit Windows ) on those files `gendef libiconv-2.dll`, this will generate libiconv2.def file
3. Then generate the static library:

   `dlltool --as-flags=--64 -m i386:x86-64 -k --output-lib libiconv2.a --input-def libiconv2.def`
4. copy libiconv2.a to proper location.

Comment: Hi, I got exactly the issue mentioned on the main question, I followed your instructions but I'm absolutely lost finding the proper location for the libivonv2.a file. Does anybody know how to find that proper location?

Comment: You can use [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) to locate the file.